# getUserMedia API not working for iOS Safari in React

Tags: html, reactjs, typescript, safari

I'm trying to access the camera on iOS through implementing the `getUserMedia` API in my React App.

I've managed to successfully implement a component that renders and works fine on Chrome however it doesn't seem to work when I navigate to `mylocalIP:3000` on iOS Safari. I would be very grateful for any pointers on where my code may be going wrong to not be compatible with iOS. [StackBlitz link to the code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-i45ldv)

```
const Video: React.FC = (props) => {
    useEffect(() => {
        start()
    })

    const constraints = {
        audio: false,
        video: true
    };

    async function start() {
        const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
        const video = document.getElementById('video') as HTMLVideoElement;
        video.setAttribute("playsinline", "true");
        video.setAttribute("controls", "true");
        video.srcObject = stream;
    }

    return (
        <video id='video' autoPlay playsInline></video>
    )
}

export default Video
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Turns out that getUserMedia [needs to be executed in an HTTPS environment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia#Security).

In `Create React App` you need to create this HTTPS environment by changing the `start` script in `package.json` to `"HTTPS=true react-scripts start"`

The iOS device will warn that the CRA has an invalid signature, however if you proceed to the site, it will then prompt you for access to the webcam.

**UPDATE:** In all my CRA projects I use [mkcert](https://github.com/FiloSottile/mkcert) to install a Certificate Authority, and then generate certificates for webpack to use when compiling the site in CRA.

In CRA project root:

`mkcert -install`

`mkdir .cert && cd $_ && mkcert localhost`

`printf "\nSSL_CRT_FILE=.cert/localhost.pem\nSSL_KEY_FILE=.cert/localhost-key.pem\nHTTPS=true" >> ../.env`

**OR** if you don't like executing random commands you don't understand:

1. Create a `.cert/` folder in the project root
2. Change directory into the `.cert/` folder in your terminal
3. Run `mkcert localhost`
4. Create a `.env` file in your project root
5. Inside this file add the following:

```yaml
SSL_CRT_FILE=.cert/localhost.pem
SSL_KEY_FILE=.cert/localhost-key.pem
HTTPS=true
```

Comment: And how to make it works in heroku? I have the app uploaded in HTTPS but nothing works