# Use mkcert certificate for local testing of PWA

Tags: android, ssl, ssl-certificate, progressive-web-apps

I'm trying to setup a local dev environment for a PWA I'm working on. 
I have installed mkcert on my Mac and am able to host a https://localhost version on my computer. 
Now I'd like to open the page on my Android phone. On the mkcert github it says:

> Mobile devices
>
> For the certificates to be trusted on mobile devices,
>   you will have to install the root CA. It's the rootCA.pem file in the
>   folder printed by mkcert -CAROOT.
>
> On iOS, you can either use AirDrop, email the CA to yourself, or serve
>   it from an HTTP server. After installing it, you must enable full
>   trust in it. Note: earlier versions of mkcert ran into an iOS bug, if
>   you can't see the root in "Certificate Trust Settings" you might have
>   to update mkcert and regenerate the root.
>
> For Android, you will have to install the CA and then enable user
>   roots in the development build of your app. See this StackOverflow
>   answer.
>
> https://github.com/FiloSottile/mkcert

I installed the rootCA.pem on my phone. The part about "enabling user roots" doesn't apply, since this is not an app.

But when I open the page on my phone using https://[my-local-network-ip]:1234 I get a warning, that the certificate can't be trusted.

How can I trust the certificate so I can locally test the PWA on my phone?

Comment: Might it just be easier to push your PWA to a free HTTPS host for testing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with your goal - running a local TLS based setup can be useful in terms of productivity and early troubleshooting.

Your problem is DNS based and you need to access the TLS secured URL via the host name.

The only way you'll get DNS to match up on the Android side is to use an HTTP proxy, while running either an emulator or a device connected via USB.

In a nutshell I would do this:

- Issue your cert to a more real world domain name such as mycompany.com
- Add this domain name to DNS on your Mac book
- Install a free proxy such as [proxyman](https://proxyman.io/) on the Mac
- Configure the Android emulator or device to use the proxy (you will also need to trust the proxy's cert on Android and the Mac)
- Then browse to https://mycompany.com from Android

Full details are available in [my write up](https://authguidance.com/2018/02/21/android-https-debugging/)

Answer (score 7):

I know you've probably moved on from this question, as it's almost a year on. However, I would like to share how I was able to test my PWA locally in a secure context.

Not making any assumptions about what framework / packaging / build system you're using:

1. Generate a certificate & key using `mkcert`. If you are hosting your PWA locally & want to access it over your local IP address i.e. `192.168.1.x:3000` you also need to tell `mkcert` to generate a certificate that covers that IP address:

```js
mkcert localhost 192.168.1.17

// The certificate is at "./localhost+1.pem" and the key at "./localhost+1-key.pem" ✅
```

**Important note**: most routers dynamically assign local IP addresses, so it's worthwhile assigning a static IP.

2. Install your RootCA from `mkcert` onto your iOS or Android device. Follow the instructions in the [mkcert docs](https://github.com/FiloSottile/mkcert#mobile-devices)
3. Serve your generated certificates with your web server of choice. I use Create React App. You can see my answer about [PWAs in secure context here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59461993/getusermedia-api-not-working-for-ios-safari-in-react/59505088#59505088)